# How do I install a Wacom Bamboo Fun?

Tags: 10.10, input-devices, wacom, bamboo, graphics-tablet

I own a Wacom Bamboo Fun CTH-661 and would like to know how I make it work on Ubuntu 10.10. I am a Linux newbie trying to migrate from Windows, so it would be wonderful to have a step-by-step answer.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got my Bamboo "Pen" working on 10.10.

As suggested by Chris Jester-Young, the driver in the kernel isn't new enough.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver

Use the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
```

Comment: I've managed to get it to work on 10.10, too! Simply followed the instructions on: http://www.skritter.com/forum/topic?id=51345959. It is working!

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, the wacom configuration is not one of the things that has made it to "automatic plug and play" level yet with Ubuntu,** but I'm very happy that we have working drivers at all.

**Most wacoms will work out of the box with ubuntu 9.10+.**  This means pointer and pressure-sensitivity, and default configuration for the buttons.

As Ryan said above, xserver-xorg-input-wacom is the wacom driver that comes installed by default in Ubuntu 10+. **However, this will not necessarily mean all your buttons are working how you want them to be.** To get everything else working, there is a little bit of configuration involved, and you may have to do some googling to figure out how to get your particular model working.

This is something that can be *(Hopefully!) solved with the **[Linux-wacom-project's](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index.php/howto/xsetwacom) wacom-tools** package; this is an extra utility that allows creates specific settings for your wacom tablet.

I was using this up until ubuntu Karmic, but I have not determined wether this is yet working on ubuntu Maverick.  Last I checked, it wasn't working for me.

But for starters:

1. **Google your question**.
   See if anyone has already gotten your model of wacom working yet in Ubuntu Maverick.
2. **Go to the Ubuntu wiki Wacom page:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom.
3. **[Check out the Ubuntu forums](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wacom-tools#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=qdr%3ay&q=site%3aubuntuforums.org+wacom-tools+10.10&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&tbo=1&fp=c5dfae954573bc9c)** for the same question.

   -- Edit: -- See this forums thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1423278&page=1
4. **--IF--** someone has gotten their Bamboo fun working with wacom-tools/xsetwacom, **head to the linux-wacom-project [howto page](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index.php/howto/xsetwacom)** and figure out how to change the settings for your various buttons and inputs.
5. **Please post here if you get any answers!**

Comment: Thanks for the information. Although I have xserver-xorg-input-wacom installed, the tablet doesn't work (I have to work with a mouse). I have seen the links you provided but for a linux newbie they seem a bit difficult... I was hoping there was an easier way to make it work.

Comment: I hear you, aren't we all?
sorry for your experience, there's generally been good out-of-the-box support for at the very least the basic utilities of the wacom tablets since Jaunty. If it's not working for you as it should be, then the only solutions here are going to come from research, unforunately.

Comment: Thanks. Research, here I come! By the way, do you know any command to see if the tablet is being recognized?

Comment: List recognized devices:  `xsetwacom --list`

Comment: Just found this forum thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1423278&page=1

This should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software package called "xserver-xorg-input-wacom" that provides support for the Bamboo and other Wacom tablets. On Ubuntu 10.10, that package comes pre-installed.

To verify this for yourself, go to System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager, then search for "wacom" in the field in the upper right hand corner. If the checkbox next to "xserver-xorg-input-wacom" is green, then your computer is already prepared to use your Bamboo tablet.

Comment: IIRC, that is not enough. There is also a kernel module that needs to be updated from the Linux Wacom drivers site, if you're using the very latest products.

Comment: Yes, I have the xserver-xorg-input-wacom installed but the tablet doesn't work...